# Problem with probability

Tags: probability-theory, recreational-mathematics

If we choose randomly an infinite, countable set of disks in $\mathbb R^2$, what is the probability that intersection of every pair of disks from the set is an empty set?

EDIT: Because the problem in the above stated form is too hard to handle, or undecidable, or it may have many different solutions depending on the way we choose the centers and the radii I will state it with extra conditions.

First variant of the problem: Add to the original problem: "all disks have the same radius $R$".

Second variant of the problem: Add to the original problem "all disks have the same radius $R>1$ and every center has the coordinates $(x,y)$, where $x,y \in\mathbb Z$"

Question for the first and second variant of the problem: Is the problem solvable in at least one of these two variants or we need more extra conditions?

Comment: "choose randomly" is not a well-defined prescription. It can sometimes be interpreted as a well-defined prescription, in cases where there is an obvious candidate for the most natural distribution to consider, e.g. a uniform distribution. This is not such a case.

Comment: Do you want to say that this problem can`t be solved with the information I provided?

Comment: Essentially. You need to specify what "randomly" means. I.e, from what distributions are we choosing the centre coordinates and radii?

Comment: Do you think that something changes if we set that all disks have the same radius?

Comment: That's a good start, but then you still haven't said anything about how to choose the centres. Are they supposed to be a Poisson process? If so, the answer would be zero, independent of the product of the density of the centres and the area of the disks (which would otherwise also need to be specified).

Comment: I think I understand what two of you want to say, that the answer depends on how i define "choosing the centres"?

Comment: But if I define probabilistically how centres are chosen then they are not completely randomly chosen, right?

Comment: No, I think that's a misconception. In mathematics, there's no such thing as "completely randomly". "Randomly" always means "randomly according to some distribution (implied or stated)"; "randomly" isn't well-defined if you don't specify a distribution. In the present case, your intuitive notion of "completely randomly" probably corresponds to a Poisson process, but even then you need to specify the density -- there's no "natural" density implied in the idea of "complete randomness".

Comment: Now I have edited the problem, what is your opinion about the edited version?

Comment: Unfortunately, $\Bbb Z^2$ is still an unbounded set and does not admit for any natural distribution such as the uniform one. Are you coming up with this problem by yourself? In such a case, do you have some *particular* interest in it, or it's just interesting to you?

Comment: Yes, I created the problem and it is just interesting to me and somehow I believe that the second variant can be solved but I do not know how?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, some natural formulations of this problem are *extremely* difficult. Take a finite square with side-lengths $n$ and then make it periodic by identifying opposite sides, i.e. making it a torus. Then you can uniformly pick the centers of each circle within the rectangle. This is called the "Pennies on a carpet problem" or "2-D hard-spheres model." The problem is *extremely* difficult and not too much is known about it. [You can find a bit more info here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37438/pennies-on-a-carpet-problem)